# How do I replace all occurrences of string in Word documents in a folder

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

I've managed to find& edit per one word file. With this code:

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\users\stefan\test\New Microsoft Word Document.docx") 
$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 

$FindText = "that" 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = "this" 
$wdFindContinue = 1 

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objWord.Quit()
```

But I want to do it for whole folder. I've tried to insert something like this:

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

 $list = Get-ChildItem "c:\users\stefan\test\*.*" -Include *.doc*
 foreach($item in $list){
 $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($list.FullName,$true)

 $objSelection = $objWord.Selection 

$FindText = "Sara" 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = "AJMOO" 
$wdFindContinue = 1 

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objWord.Quit()
}
```

Also, it changes only one item that is found, but I want all items in the file.
Thanks.

Comment: I have yet to test but I see one potential big issue. `$wdFindContinue` is used _before_ it is defined. `$wdFindContinue = 1` should come before you assign it to `$wrap`. Does that change anything? This would possibly make the first file not work but subsequent might be fine. Either way that should be changed.

Comment: @Matt, i will check this concern now, and I will let you now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Multiple Replacements

> Also, it changes only one item that is found, but I want all items in the file

This is because you have not set the scope of the replacement to be all items. The is from the next argument you did not specify in your [Execute method call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977.aspx). Set a variable called [`$wdReplaceAll` and set it to 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdreplace.aspx). Then you adjust your call to add that variable.

```
$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$wdReplaceAll)
```

That fixes that issue when run against one file.

## Multiple Files

> But I want to do it for whole folder

The partial issue with that is your are not properly querying the folder for files. `-Include` is finicky and work when partnered with `-Recurse` however you are treating it like a `-Filter` anyway so adjust as such.

```
$list = Get-ChildItem "c:\users\stefan\test\" -filter "*.doc*"
```

Next, when you are looping you are not using the current iteration but the whole collection when calling `.open()`

```
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($list.FullName,$true)
```

Should instead be

```
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)
```

as per your loop definition.

Now you need to be sure you close each document *before* you quit the application. Right now you are quitting word inside the loop.

```
foreach($item in $list){
    #.... Stuff and things happens here.
    $objDoc.Save()
    $objDoc.Close()
}

$objWord.Quit()
```

## Variable declaration and calls

Right now you set `$wrap` to the value of the variable `$wdFindContinue`. When that is first called `$wdFindContinue` is null as it is not set to a few lines later in the code.

```
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
#...
$wdFindContinue = 1
```

Switch the order of these lines or just set `$wrap` directly to 1. I am unsure of the implications of this being incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Thankfully to @Matt I've solved my code.

Here is a correct version which works:

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

$list = Get-ChildItem "c:\users\stefan\test\*.*" -Include *.doc*
foreach($item in $list){
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)

$objSelection = $objWord.Selection 
$wdFindContinue = 1
$FindText = "Sara" 
$MatchCase = $False 
$MatchWholeWord = $true
$MatchWildcards = $False 
$MatchSoundsLike = $False 
$MatchAllWordForms = $False 
$Forward = $True 
$Wrap = $wdFindContinue 
$Format = $False 
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$ReplaceWith = "AJMOO" 
$wdFindContinue = 1 
$ReplaceAll = 2

$a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText,$MatchCase,$MatchWholeWord, ` 
$MatchWildcards,$MatchSoundsLike,$MatchAllWordForms,$Forward,` 
$Wrap,$Format,$ReplaceWith,$ReplaceAll) 
$objDoc.Save()
$objDoc.Close()
}
$objWord.Quit()
```