# Replacing all occurrences of a string in a Word file by an hyperlink

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I have to create a Powershell script that reads a Word file (.docx) and replaces strings by hyperlinks. So far, based on [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552217/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-string-in-word-documents-in-a-folder), I can replace all occurrences of a string by another string easily. With [that script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/06/24/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-add-hyperlinks-to-a-word-document/), I can look for a string and replace it by an hyperlink. However, only the first occurrence is replaced.

Here's my understanding of the problem so far :

The first script uses the `ReplaceWith` and `Replace=wdReplaceAll` parameters of the `Execute` function of the `Find` Interface. The issue is that `ReplaceWith` expects a String and not an Hyperlink object.

The second script doesn't specify those parameters so it only uses the `Find.Execute()` function to move the start of the Range object to the found string and then insert a link at that position.

Since I can't replace all occurrences at once, I'd try to iterate through all matches to insert links at their location. But `Find.Execute()` only returns a Boolean... Now I'm thinking of maybe redefining the range to exclude the found occurrence and looping until the end of the doc, but this feels complicated.

Let's say I've got a Word file with this text :

> In other words, each of the articles linked here is an index to
>   multiple lists on a topic. Some of the linked articles are themselves
>   lists of lists of lists. This article is also a list of lists.

Here's a bare bone script that replace only the first occurrence of "lists" by a relative link. I'm trying to replace all occurrences of "lists" to the hyperlink $linkPath, but can't find how. Help ?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$wdunits = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdunits" -as [type]
$objWord = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application  
$objWord.Visible = $false

# Text to find and replace by a link
$findText = "lists"
# Link to file
$linkPath = ".\Untitled.png"
# Source Word (2007+) file
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open([FILE TO READ FROM])
# Resulting file
$saveAs = [FILE TO SAVE TO]
# Set Range to all document content
$range = $objDoc.Content
$range.movestart($wdunits::wdword,$range.start) | Out-Null

# Execute params
$matchCase = $false
$matchWholeWord = $true
$matchWildcards = $false
$matchSoundsLike = $false
$matchAllWordForms = $false
$forward = $true 
$wrap = 1
$format = $False
$wdReplaceNone = 0 
$wdFindContinue = 1
$wdReplaceAll = 2

# $wordFound is true is $findText is found in $range. 
# $range.find.execute modifies the start of the range 
$wordFound = $range.find.execute($findText,$matchCase,`
             $matchWholeWord,$matchWildCards,$matchSoundsLike,`
             $matchAllWordForms,$forward,$wrap)

if($wordFound){
        $objDoc.Hyperlinks.Add($range,$linkPath,$null,$null,$findText) | Out-Null
}
$objDoc.SaveAs($saveAs)
$objDoc.Close()
$objWord.Quit()
$rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
[gc]::Collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**Reference**

- [Find Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.find?view=word-pia)
- [Find.Execute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute?view=word-pia)
- [Range Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range?view=word-pia)
- [Hyperlinks Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.hyperlinks)

Answer (score 1):

As with any dataset you have to loop to hit all items in the data set to take action on specific in the dataset. You are not doing this in your code. In MSWord, you need to walk the document. For example I am show code for deletes, but this just as well could be your replace effort.

Example: VBA for just delete any hyper link

```
Sub RemoveHyperlinksInDoc()
    ' You need to delete collection members starting from the end going backwards
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Hyperlinks(i).Delete
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Example PowerShell for delete all hyperlinks

```
Param
(
    [string]$Document = $Word.Documents.Open((Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the full path to the Word document'))
)

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.application
$Hyperlinks = @($Document.Hyperlinks)  
$hyperlinks | ForEach { $_.Delete() }
$document.save()
$document.Close()
$word.quit()
```

Example: PowerShell for delete only image hyperlinks

```
Param
(
    [string]$Document = $Word.Documents.Open((Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the full path to the Word document'))
)

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.application
$Hyperlinks = @($Document.Hyperlinks) 
$Hyperlinks | ForEach {
                         If ($_.Shape) {$_.Delete()}
                         Else {$_.Name;Write-Warning -Message 'Hyperlink is not a graphic and will not be removed'}
                      }
$Document.save()
$Document.Close()
$Word.quit()
```

Comment: Yeah I pretty much figured that since I couldn't replace all occurrences at once, I would have to iterate through all occurrences I need to replace. The hard part was that I was replacing words with link.

I did find a solution which involves counting the number of occurrences and using find.execute to move the range. I'll be posting it soon, thanks for your help.

Comment: @TheTardis «I pretty much figured that since I couldn't replace all occurrences at once». You can if you put the replacement hyperlink (not just the url) into the clipboard, then use Word's Find/Replace function, with ^c as the replacement expression.

Comment: @macropod That's a great advice and I'm much closer to what I had in mind initially. I can't find how to put a link in the clipboard however. If I manually copy a link from Word to the clipboard before running my script, it pastes it perfectly.  How do I create a link via VBA and add it to the clipboard? I don't think I can use Hyperlinks.add since it asks for an anchor...

Comment: @TheTardis You could, for example, programmatically create the hyperlink in a document, then copy or cut it from there to the clipboard.