# How to run Break Link option in Powershell for Multiple word document

Tags: powershell

I have word files in folder D:\xxx.docx, There are images in it but those are externally linked.
Now i want to save the docx file with Break link so that the document becomes document with embedded images.

I Found some code but not sure how to put it properly , can any one help please

```
$wrd = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$doc = $wrd.Documents.Open('C:\test.rtf')
$opt = [ref][Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::WdFormatRTF
$name= [ref]'C:\test.rtf'
$wrd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs($name, $opt)
$wrd.ActiveDocument.Close()
$wrd.Quit()

    $images = $doc.InlineShapes              
    foreach ($image in $images) {            
      $linkFormat = $image.LinkFormat        
      $linkFormat.SavePictureWithDocument = 1
      $linkFormat.BreakLink()                
    }
```

Comment: You cannot do this without calling without Word (COM). There are plenty of examples online and videos on Youtube about how to use PowerShell to work with Word, Excel, etc., docs. Also, SO Rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I Found some code but not sure how to put it properly , can any one help please

Comment: To be able to do this on multiple files, this is what Get-ChildItem is for. Use GCI to find all the files, Open MSWord COM only once, then loop over the files, piping the name to the loop, to make the changes. then close MSWord and exit your script.

Comment: @ Postanote , Could you write the code please what you are suggesting  . the first 7 lines many not be required as i already have rtf files.

Comment: here is the step what i do manually in doc file  but want to do it in Powershell : Open a docx file or rtf file in MS word, insert a picture . lets say the pc is located in a folder d:\pic.png.now save the file as docx and share it to someone. when he open the doc file he will not see the picture  because the picture file location is missing for him. so manual fix is to to break link to your document and save it then send it to other person. So what ever i am doing here i want to do it with powershell. The code i shared many not be correct which i collect from different sources from Web

Comment: Therefore i need help to put the code in correct form. the other word for break link is "Unlinking"

Comment: The easiest way to learn to do this sort of thing is to first look at the examples in the built-in help files, say for GCI [Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full], once you get your head around that, as Open a Word doc, start the macro recorder, do the steps for your use case, stop the macro recorder,  copy that code into the PowerShell ISE or VSCode, and modify that for your use case. MSOffice macros are just VBA code, that you'd just convert to a PowerShell use case. There are SO Q&A's with samples of PowerShell using Word COM. So, your query is really a duplicate or close to one already on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. See this SO Q&A similar to your use case:

[Replacing all occurrences of a string in a Word file by an hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344154/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-word-file-by-an-hyperlink/53348317#53348317)

Though the OP there is talking about replacement, it's the same approach for removal.